# Is the question "Whose children dropped off at his house?" correct?

Tags: questions

The sentence is:

> Tom's aunt dropped the children off at Tom's house.

I mean they are children of Tom's aunt

Can I say:

> Whose children dropped off at his house?

Is it correct grammatically?

Comment: What do you mean? Your question is wrong and it is unanswerable because we don't know whose children they are.

Comment: They are children of Tom's aunt.now by this information is it true?

Comment: No. It's not true. They maybe anybody's children or children of different families. Tom's aunt simply dropped the off the Tom's house.

Comment: They are children of Tom's aunt but I had forgotten explain it in my sentences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is grammatical, but it means something different than what you want to ask.

The phrasal verb **to drop off** has a few different usages and meanings; in this case, you're using the *transitive* version, where the subject of the sentence (Tom's Aunt) is depositing the object of the sentence (the children).

When you change the sentence into a question, you need for the main actor to still be the person doing the depositing. You can do this directly, if you're wondering about who did the depositing:

> **Who dropped off** the children at Tom's house? (Who = subject/actor = Tom's Aunt).

But if you're changing the subject to be the children themselves, because that's who you're wondering about, you need to use a passive construction so it's still clear that it is Tom's Aunt who was the actor:

> Whose children **were dropped off** [by Tom's aunt] at Tom's house? (Omitted "Tom's Aunt" = passive actor)

If you don't use this passive construction, then the children become the actors in the question.

> Whose children **dropped off** at Tom's house? (Children = subject/actor)

This means that you no longer are using the transitive version of the verb phrase "to drop off" because there's no hint of an object in this version—no person or thing is depositing or being deposited by the children. This is a problem because there actually are a few different intransitive meanings for this verb phrase. Possible interpretations become:

> Whose children **fell asleep** at Tom's house?
>   Whose children **withdrew [from something, like a race]** at Tom's house?
>   Whose children **died** at Tom's house?

And so forth.

Comment: That's a really clear and complete answer.

Comment: @1006a Tnx I got it :) , Excuse me where are you from?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I'm from the US, mostly Midwest.